# Convert Latitude Longitude to SQL-Server Geography

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-xe5

I have coordinates as two double values, latitude and longitude. I need to somehow convert them to the SQL-Server Geography datatype.

I have a working example for this in C#, but I don't know how to do it in Delphi.
The aim is to retrieve the same data as I get when accessing the `SqlGeographyBinary` in my example, to save it in an text file.

```
public Double Latitude { get; set; }

public Double Longitude { get; set; }

private String sqlGeographyBinary = null;
public String SqlGeographyBinary
{
    get
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sqlGeographyBinary))
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
                {
                    var sqlPoint = SqlGeography.Point(Latitude, Longitude, SRID);
                    sqlPoint.Write(writer);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    var buffer = new Byte[stream.Length];
                    stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                    sqlGeographyBinary = BitConverter.ToString(buffer).Replace("-", "");
                    writer.Close();
                }
           }
        }        
        return sqlGeographyBinary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything in Delphi yet?

Comment: I have no clue with which functions of which Unit I should work, so no... I'm lacking an approach to start with

Answer (score 1):

The `SqlGeography` type is a .NET type that is not natively supported by Delphi so there is no straightforward way to do what you want without either exporting the C# function to a DLL or having an MSSQL server to do the type generation for you.

For the latter, as a solution, this is completely untested as I don't have a database to try this, but from [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DbExpress_Data_Type_Mapping_for_Supported_Databases) it sounds like SQL Server can construct and interpret the types for you.  ie :

```
insert into MyTable (geographyCol) values (someParam)
```

where you would define the parameter as a `TDBXDataTypes.AnsiStringType` like :

```
someParam --> 'SqlGeography.Point(Latitude, Longitude, SRID)'
```

likewise, reading the field :

```
Select geographyCol.ToString() from MyTable
```

would return the [Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) Well-Known Text (WKT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) representation of the `SqlGeograhpy` instance.  You could also, I assume, return any other property in a similar manner.

Comment: I know this is possible, but I have existing infrastructure which forces me to save my data as the well known text in a file.

Comment: @FlorianKoch ...so you don't need to (and specifically cannot!) actually connect to or insert this object into a database or create a binary type but you rather need to generate the WKT and save it *to a file* from latitude, longitude and SRID?  What platforms do you need to support?  Your C# code uses `sqlPoint.Write(writer);`, which is a binary serialization - it does not create WKT (afaik).  It seems now that it is not entirely clear what your objective is.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was wrong - I don't need to insert the well known text, but the serialized data. Yes, I need to save the data to an xml-file, which then can be provided to customers to import into our application.

Comment: @FlorianKoch Then the simplest solution, since you already have a working C# implementation, is to simply export to a DLL and call the DLL from within delphi.

Comment: I already thought about this, though I wanted to avoid it - but maybe it's really the easiest way

Comment: After fighting with .NET-DLL usage in Delphi I managed to get it running through my C# code.